# How can I use my USB flash drive again after I zeroed it out in Disks?

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, format

I've used the "Disks" utility to zero out a USB flash drive (pendrive). Now it's not showing up anymore as a usable storage medium.

I need to use this usb drive (of 4 GB) again to write an OS image to it to re-image an old laptop, however I can't seem to do anything with it at this point.

Where do I go from here? I have no clue where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: What "zeroed" means?

Comment: @ruda.almeida Overwriting the whole drive with zeroes is what that means usually.

Comment: @gertvdijk Agreed, but in this context the OP could also mean "removed all the partitions". Not sure if the distinction matters here.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Well, if you zero out the first 512 bytes your [partition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries) is gone too... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First re-install a partition table on it. You can do this in GParted or any other generic partition table editor. **Make sure you select the right device** in the top right corner of the window. Then in menu *Device* -> *Create partition table* and select the good-old MSDOS partition table layout.
2. Create a new partition. Choose a nice file system you like to use (e.g. FAT32, Ext3, ...)
3. Apply all changes.
4. Re-plug the pendrive in the PC. Should work again!

Comment: Lord, bless this man, for he has saved my many hours of sleep.

Comment: Thank you sir! Sorry, it's my first time posting, I have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: @Mike No problem, that's why I was suggesting it. You'll find out more later by using this site more, don't worry! :)